# Prisma/ PostgreSQL: What are are the user privileges required while using Prisma with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I am using PostgreSQL as my database along with Prisma as my ORM.It seems to be giving an issue while running the 'prisma migrate' command on the server which seems to be an issue of user database privileges not being present.What are the basic user privileges that are required for Prisma while using Postgres apart from the option of giving full admin rights?

Comment: Have you set up the [basic connection](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch/relational-databases/connect-your-database-typescript-postgres) with .env file?

Comment: Yes I have setup the env file database URL

Answer (score 1):

Database user needs to have a `CREATEDB` privilege for using `migrate` commands in PostgreSQL.

Here's a reference to privileges needed for each supported database: [Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/shadow-database#shadow-database-user-permissions).

[image: Database Privilege]